# how to optimize this part of code

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to optimize this code to minimum.

```
Dictionary<long, string> developmentRegions = objectset
    .Where(f => f.IsDeleted == false && f.IsApproved == true)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a.Name);
```

Can anyone optimize this code

Comment: Why sql-server tag, is this `Linq-To-Sql` or `Linq-To-Entities`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about optimizing working code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probaly is the order of query resul.

Try on SQL Server create a index on Name field, for take a fester result on order.

```
CREATE INDEX ixName ON TableWhereNameIsField (NameOfOrderField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You really need all those names loaded from database, there is little You can do. You can remove the OrderBy, as Dictionary does not guarantee order anyway.